# How to check if JPG file contains other types of images

Tags: image, format, hex, jpeg, contains

I have jpg file, i can decode it to hex so it is possible to read the inside of file. I have a question, there is any possibility that between `SOI` and `EOI` markers there is another image format image hidden ?? The whole file size is around `950kb`. I checked for more `SOI` `EOI` markers of jpg and i didn't find others so i think i can exclude the possibility of another jpg file inside.

So about other formats it is possible that jpg contains one and how i can check if there is one and even retrieve it ??

I were using this website for analysis after i found that this file is JFIF.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format

The whole header is below, as you can see it starts from `SOI`, then informations about jfif are specified. The thumbnail image pixel size is `0x0` in this header.

```
FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00
```

it ends with

```
FF D9
```

Comment: it's website related to code and software development, it may be you can provide some code snippet you've been trying so far, so at least it's understandable what tools you've been using for this purposes and people can give you more specific answer

Comment: I've added some more informations, i were searching for any file type markers like jfif. but i didnt found any of them here

Answer (score 0):

There could easily be a thumbnail in an APPn marker. Take a look at the JFIF specification, for example.

Such an image would have to be relatively small because APP and COM markers are limited to 64K.

Comment: I didn't found any specificiation that covers COM marker yet. The whole header before scan don't exceed 50 bytes of information, There is also information that there is no thumbnail in `APP0` marker as i described in my question, the width and hight are `0 x 0` and the whole file dont contain `FF E1` which would say that there is APP1 marker . The question is, if there is a COM marker it can have thumbnail inside of this scan or it should be listed before the scan of this one big jpg file ?? If yes how i can interpret other markers than APPn that is described.

Comment: A COM marker or an APPn marker could contain an image. I have never seen it for a COM marker but it could be done. I have seen it for APPn markers.

Comment: Hmmm... The whole file contain only APP0 marker, and its the insides of it so i don't think COM marker would have a thumbnail inside. After all researches i've done i were not able to find any hidden images / thumbnails in the file so i think there is none at all and further analysis is pointless. Thank you for your effort.